# group data in arraylist according to same Id

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a problem I want to create a new arraylist as have to send it other class .
I cannot post my original problem so copied the data.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Grouping {
     List<Student> studlist1 = new ArrayList<Student>();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studlist = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studlist.add(new Student("1", "John", "New York"));
        studlist.add(new Student("1", "Max", "California"));
        studlist.add(new Student("2", "Andrew", "Los Angeles"));
        studlist.add(new Student("3", "Michael", "New York"));
        studlist.add(new Student("3", "Sam", "California"));
        studlist.add(new Student("4", "Mark", "New York"));

        Map<String, List<Student>> groupedStudents = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();
        for (Student student: studlist) {
            String key = student.stud_id;
            if (groupedStudents.containsKey(key)) {
                List<Student> list = groupedStudents.get(key);
                list.add(student);
                }
            else {
            List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
            list.add(student);
            groupedStudents.put(key, list);}  
        }


        Set<String> groupedStudentsKeySet = groupedStudents.keySet();
        int index = 0;
        for (String id: groupedStudentsKeySet) {
            List<Student> stdnts = groupedStudents.get(id);

            for (Student student : stdnts) {
//               Want to create a new arraylist as belows.Grouing data in arraylist according to same ID
//                 arraylist will be as
//
//                 index 0: 1,John,New York,Max,Califoornia
//                 index 1: 2, Andrew, Los Angeles
//                 index 2: 3,Michael, New York, "Sam", California
//                 index 3: 4,Mark, New York


            }

        }

    }
}

class Student {

    String stud_id;
    String stud_name;
    String stud_location;

    Student(String sid, String sname, String slocation) {

        this.stud_id = sid;
        this.stud_name = sname;
        this.stud_location = slocation;

    }
}
```

Want to create a new arraylist as belows.Grouing data in arraylist according to same ID

Arraylist should be as
   index 0: 1,John,New York,Max,Califoornia

index 1: 2, Andrew, Los Angeles

index 2: 3,Michael, New York, "Sam", California

index 3: 4,Mark, New York

Just want the same arraylist as above

Comment: Any Solution for the question

Answer (score 0):

I've suggested earlier to check 'groupingBy' methods in Stream Api(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236902/group-data-in-arraylist?noredirect=1#comment100976235_57236902), what you trying to do can be done in one line:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> collect = studlist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStud_id));
```

It's not list by indexes, but I suppose its even more convenient.

Don't forget to add getter to your `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (groupedStudents.containsKey(key)) {
            groupedStudents.get(key).add(student);
            }
```

Use this code.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Want to create a new arraylist.not adding to map itself

Comment: It will add student object to an existing list stored in the map. Try it.